# JQuery select dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic

In my page i'm generating a list with an ajax call, somehow like this:

```
for var k in items {
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        someElement.append("<li data-id='"+k+"' class='dynamic'>"+items[k]+"</li>";
    }
}
```

That works as expected.
Now on a button click, I'd like to remove items which have a class '.dynamic'

```
myBtn.on("click", function() {
    $(".dynamic").remove();
});
```

But none of the newly added elements gets selected.

I know, how to add listneres to dynamically added elements using .on(). 
Is there some method to select them also?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to target an element that exists on page load, and make use of **[event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)**.

The second parameter passed into **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** should be the dynamically-created element that you wish to attach the `click` event handler to:

```
$("document").on("click", myBtn, function() {
  $(".dynamic").remove();
});
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, after about a half an hour of debugging and trying everything i noticed a typo in my class name.